# x86 assembly 32 bit program stuck on how to finish main

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

```
; This program computes 1+x+y+x^2+y^2+x^3+y^3


INCLUDE Irvine32.inc 

.data

    xinput BYTE "Enter the value of x :  ",0
    yinput BYTE "Enter the value of y :  ",0
    total BYTE "The value of f(x,y) is : ",0

.code
main PROC

mov edx, OFFSET xinput




        mov ebp, OFFSET yinput
        call WriteString
        mov ebx, 1
        call ReadHex
        mov edx, eax
        mov esp, eax
        add ebx, eax
        add ebp, eax
        call squarex
        add ebx, eax
        mov eax, edx
        call squarey
        add ebp, eax
        mov eax, esp
        call cubex
        add ebx, eax
        mov eax, edx
        call cubey
        add ebp, eax
        mov eax, esp
        mov edx, OFFSET total
        mov esp, OFFSET total
        call WriteString
        call crlf
        mov eax, ebx
        call WriteHex
        call crlf
        exit

squarex PROC

        push ecx
        push edx
        mov ecx, eax
        mov eax, 0
    loop1:
        add eax, edx
        loop loop1
        pop edx
        pop ecx
        ret

squarex ENDP

squarey PROC

        push ecx
        push esp
        mov ecx, eax
        mov eax, 0
    loop1:
        add eax, esp
        loop loop1
        pop esp
        pop ecx
        ret

squarey ENDP

cubex PROC

        push ecx
        push edx
        mov ecx, eax
        call squarex
        mov edx, eax
        mov eax, 0
    loop1:
        add eax, edx
        loop loop1
        pop edx
        pop ecx
        ret

cubex ENDP

cubey PROC

        push ecx
        push esp
        mov ecx, eax
        call squarey
        mov esp, eax
        mov eax, 0
    loop1:
        add eax, esp
        loop loop1
        pop esp
        pop ecx
        ret

cubex ENDP
```

I am confused how to finish off my main PROC to store all values in eax and compile this program. Any help?

I think I am really close to having this done, I have run into fatal errors on my loops (cubex) but I don't really understand where to go from here to finishing this program off.

Comment: I would avoid storing things in `esp` if I were you... I haven't seen `push esp` or `pop esp` instuctions recently, though I am excited by the idea... Did you consider the `mul` instruction at all ?  It's not the quickest instruction on earth, but probably quicker than repeated addition.  It's not clear to me why you have two `square` and two `cube` functions.  A single function, taking the value to be squared or cubed in `eax` would be enough, perhaps ?  Without knowing what `WriteString` and `ReadHex` do, it's hard to suggest how

Comment: How do you expect the `pop esp` to work if you modify `esp`???

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows:

Restore ebx, ebp and esp registers and call `ret` to exit.

If you are on linux:

Call `int 80h` with eax = 1 and ebx = 0.